# Downloading map of each region of Tanzania?

Tags: data, tanzania

I need to download good resolution map of each region (total 30 according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_Tanzania)) of Tanzania. The maps should contain major roads, thematic land cover and landmarks.

This map of Tanzania may help to find the areas.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for raster or vector maps?

Comment: Have you tried openstreetmap.org ?

Comment: Vector/ raster anything will do. Yes, I tried to download OSM but they seem to need a lot of GIS work, besides they doesn't seem to have much info for few region. I was looking if someone already have them ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [datasets](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) available from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/). If you select you country (Tanzania), you will access to data (as raster or vector maps) about:

- Administrative areas;
- Inland waters;
- Roads;
- Railroads;
- Elevation;
- Land cover;
- Population.

For example, this is the shapefile of roads:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will work for now. Not that precise is every extent, doesn't bother me anyway.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. If I find any other resource, I will add it to the answer.